# Is it possible to set a Git config for all users in a system?

Tags: git

Suppose I need to set a git alias that every user in the system has to use. Instead of asking each user to add this config to their `$HOME/.gitconfig`, is it possible to declare this once globally for all users?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES) say:

> If not set explicitly with `--file`, there are four files where `git config` will search for configuration options:
>
> **`$GIT_DIR/config`**
>   Repository specific configuration file.
>
> **`~/.gitconfig`**
>   User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.
>
> **`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`**
>   Second user-specific configuration file. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/config` will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in `~/.gitconfig`. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.
>
> **`$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`**
>   System-wide configuration file.

So:

- `/etc/gitconfig` is global
- `~/.gitconfig` and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` are per user
- `$GIT_DIR/config` is per repo

In order to set a system wide option, do `git config --add --system <OPTION>`

Comment: Thanks! I always forget to RTFM before asking :)

Comment: Minor correction: The `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` file is the primary account-local configuration, `~/.gitconfig` is fallback if the previous one doesn't exist. Better be careful there is only _one_ of them, otherwise you can edit the wrong one until you are blue in the face...

Comment: @eckes, shame on you. Instead of you spending 5 minutes RTFMing, you have got scores of us reading your question, reading answers, pondering comments, and perhaps answering/commenting.

Comment: @vonbrand: the citation is actually copied from the official docs. I did not try for myself but
 they shouldn`t be wrong.

Comment: @eckes, for my use I'm going with the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` as I understand that to be more future-proof.

Comment: On Windows machines, the $(prefix) for the global config will usually be something like "C:\Program Files\Git".